# App/Scaffold white background changing issue in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Can anyone please point me out how to change this white background color of the app? Setting a color or background color on the Surface is having no impact. I've set the cyan background for the content inside the Scaffold just to debug the issue.

[image]

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        ...
        setContent {
            ChakkarTheme {
                Surface(
                    color = Color.Red, modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color.DarkGray)
                ) {
                    ChakkarApp()
                }
            ...
```

```
@Composable
fun ChakkarApp() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text(appTitle) }, navigationIcon = navigationIcon) },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
        floatingActionButton = {
            if (showFab) {
                FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation() {
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
                bottomNavItems.forEach { screen ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = { Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(stringResource(id = screen.resourceId)) },
                        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .background(Color.Cyan)
                .padding(paddingValues)
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = Screen.Running.route
            ) {
...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default background color of `Scaffold` is `MaterialTheme.colors.background`.

You can specify a custom value:

```
Scaffold(
    ...
    backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
)
```

For M3 it's `containerColor`:

```
Scaffold(
    ...
    containerColor = Color.DarkGray,
)
```

Comment: I think now it's called `containerColor`

Comment: @Aakash I wouldn't say "now", since material2 is not deprecated =) but yes, in M3 it has a different name, added it to my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you try add `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Black)` or `backgroundColor = Color.Black` in your `Scaffold`?

+ **Edit:**
add `Modifier` is not working. Try to add `backgroundColor` in your `Scaffold`.

Like this:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme {
    Scaffold(
        content = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp).background(color = Color.Cyan))
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Black
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the below code snippet set full background color
`Modifier.fillMaxSize()` It gives a full height and width.
`Modifier.background(Color.Grey)` By usging background can set a background color.

```
Box(
modifier = Modifier
.fillMaxSize()
.background(Color.Grey)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(
                state = rememberScrollState()
            )
    ) {
        Text(
            text = profileViewModel.loginUserDetail.lastName,
            fontSize = 18.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            fontFamily = myFontFamily,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp, 5.dp, 5.dp, 5.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it according to this code this is the new one.

```
Scaffold(
  modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
  content = {
    // Your content here
  }
)
```

this is the old one.

```
Scaffold(

    backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
)
```